# Calculating the Lebesgue decomposition of a measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

How we should calculate the Lebesgue decomposition of a measure? Please explain it with an example such I can get the whole idea behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See page 121 of "Real and complex analysis" written by "W. Rudin".